# Double step verification system for homepage

Tags: password-management, password-policy, one-time-password

I want to share some of my work with some double step verification system. 
PGP is not enough, since some of my clients cannot use it.
First, you need a password to login but you also need the code from your application for 2nd password.

**Is there any open-source application for such a system?** 
Where should I focus on determining and differentiating between such systems?

Answer (score 1):

If you have no idea about where to start, I would highly recommend using an existing provider (for example, [Authy](https://www.authy.com/)).

More info about a standard for time-based codes here — https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-based_One-time_Password_Algorithm — you can also search for existing open-source libraries based on terms used on that Wikipedia page.

Comment: Excellent answer! Is there any weaknesses in this system? How secure is it compared to systems of banks which uses external device for 2nd step verification or Google's one?

Comment: Google Authenticator uses that very same Time-based OTP algorithm. So if you implement that, you can have your users log in using the same app (or another one that uses the same standard — most do)